# Sharing source files between Client and Server side on AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there a way to share source code between the Client side and Server side on Appmaker ?

The use-cases are plenty: error message list, message code translation, permissions list etc.

Without this capability, one needs to duplicate which is of course tedious and error prone.

Thanks!